# Can't work with bucket name that has periods in it via REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the S3 REST api to manage objects in my bucket.  This is working when my bucket name has dashes in it.  For example, the host for a REST request would be `my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com`.

I have another bucket named `www.my-bucket-name.com`, which would have the following host in a rest request: `www.my-bucket-name.com.s3.amazonaws.com`.  Requests for bucket names like this will fail with `Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.`.  Per the docs, `www.my-bucket-name.com` is a valid bucket name.  Do I need to encode it somehow?  Is there some sort of alias?

Comment: I know that S3 runs into issues with periods in them in some specific situations. For example, if you want to access objects via HTTPS and you have periods in your bucket name then you will get SSL certificate errors. The reason for this is that Amazon has a wildcard cert for *.s3.amazonaws.com and if you have periods in your name then the URL will end up https://foo.bar.s3.amazonaws.com which does not match the wildcard cert. I don't know for certain but I wouldn't be surprised if periods create issues in other ways as well. If you can avoid using periods it might save you lots of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons S3 supports the virtual host method you're using, as well as the alternate, path-style method, for accessing buckets and their objects via the REST endpoint.

```
https://example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/foo
https://s3.amazonaws.com/example.com/foo
```

These reference the same object, but the second form works with SSL since the hostname matches the S3 wildcard cert (which is the problem you are experiencing -- wildcard SSL certs don't match dots in the hostname portion being wildcarded).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

There are some legitimate reasons to put dots in a bucket name.